# MVC - strongly typed views are broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I wrote a custom web control in MVC, and I did the whole csc thing to create a dll out of it.

That didn't work, but when I removed it and everything. My MVC thing broke, and it's giving me this error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.

for this line:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<className>>" %>
```

It's not liking strongly typed view now (normal views are working okay)! I'm not registering the dll anywhere anymore. I deleted the dll from bin. I even got rid of the class.

```
<compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=gibberish"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config for this assembly line under compilation:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="gibberish" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include this part from my web.config file.